# Interface Builder background

Tags: interface, background, storyboard, builder

How can I change the Interface Builder background? I find  really annoying that white background of the storyboard editor. Is it possible to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change the storyboard editors background color.

Sorry, :(

Answer (score 0):

It's bad because you don't see transparency :/

I hope apple change that soon.